# If Else In Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

Im trying to write something that has two possibilities. If the entry in the database exists then show one message box else show another.

Here is what i have so far

```
 Dim dc = New DataTestDataContext

 Try

        dc.SearchDealers(txtDealerName.Text, cmbDealerState.Text)

        If (txtDealerName.Text <> Or cmbDealerState.Text <> ) Then
            MessageBox.Show("This Dealer Doesnt Exist", "Search Dealer", _
                       MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Yes this dealer exists", "Search Dealer", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

What is a good way to code this? I have most of it filled out
Thanks

Comment: whats wrong with this?

Comment: What is DataTestDataContext?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it will fit much better to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: DataTestDataContext is what ever gets returned from my stored procedure but no matter what i put it always says something exists

"SearchDealers" is my stored procedure

Comment: Your code does not compile.  Post the real code.

Comment: In your code you write `If (txtDealerName.Text <> Or cmbDealerState.Text <> )`... <> to what??

Comment: im wondering what i should put after "<>" to make it work,would the syntax be "Nothing" or "Something" , since its a database entry i just need to know how to word it

Comment: This is not how you call stored procedure from code. Here is an example of how to call a stored procedure: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310070

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out for future reference, but this is using LINQ and no stored procedures.

```
 Dim dc As New DataTestDataContext()

    Try
        Dim q = _
            (From cvg In dc.GetTable(Of tblDealer)() _
            Where cvg.DealerName = txtDealName.Text And cvg.DealerState = cmbDealState.Text _
            Select cvg).SingleOrDefault()

        If (q Is Nothing) Then

            MessageBox.Show("No records exist for this Dealer")
        Else

            MessageBox.Show("Records exist, Edit and Click Update OR Click Delete Dealer to Remove")
        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex

    End Try
```